# how to create only one chip from the same word in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm wondering if there is away to make my input to create only one chip from the same word instead of creating duplicate.

Right now user seem like they can create "apple" "APPLE" "apPPle" "aPpLe" so I'm figuring out a way not do that and always return with lowercase "apple" even if they type something with all Uppercase or Lowercase.

I just want to create only one chip for one word. any help or suggestion will be really appreciated.

I have tried all this but still not working

```
1. this.value = $event.target.value.toUpperCase()
    this.ngModelChange.emit(this.value)

2. event.value=event.value.toLowerCase()

3. {{ value | lowercase }}
```

If I can fix this, the user might able to create "apple" "apple" multiple time but later I will prevent user from imputing the same word if "apple" is already existed/created.

Here is the project that is very similiar with mine

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-occkra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add filtering logic to `select` and `add` methods:

```js
if ((value || '').trim()) {
  if (this.allFruits.includes(value.toLowerCase()) && !this.fruits.includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
    this.fruits.push(value.trim().toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

without `include`

```js
if ((value || '').trim()) {
  if (this.allFruits.find((f) => f.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase()) && !this.fruits.find((f) => f.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase())) {
    this.fruits.push(value.trim().toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that but I'm getting error on "includes" by anychance do you know why?

Comment: es6 method on arrays you may want to add pollyfill or replace it with some other logic for checking if element is in array just used shortest notation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Hi..I'm not really sure how to do that and that's where I struggle so I would be really appreciate if you can help me out.. right now I just need user to able to create only one chip from one word.

Comment: added version without include

Comment: nvm..just delete my previous comment, my problem is already fixed.. It work so thank you so much for your help..